# Shiny script from Ubuntu bash

Tags: r, bash, ubuntu, shiny

I wanted to run with `crontab` (the system daemon used to execute desired tasks at certain times) a shiny script.

I first tried running `sh Autorun.sh`, being in the file:

```
R
shiny::runApp(...)
```

but that didn't work

I also tried writting directly `Rscript shiny::runApp(...)` but it also doesn't work

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `R -e 'shiny::runApp(...)'`. You might need to switch quotes if you're using any inside `runApp()`.

Comment: You tagged it bash and using sh to run, why?

Comment: @Molx yes!! thank you, that was it! Answer it and I give you the reputation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run code using `R` on shell, you must use the `-e` option, which stands for expression. The same thing can be done via `Rscript`.

The correct syntax is then:

```
R -e 'shiny::runApp(...)'
```

Care must be taken with the quotes if there are any in the expression being used.

For more information on other command-line options, check [An Introduction to R - Appendix B](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Invoking-R-from-the-command-line).